# Resetting form after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, reset

I have this code `

```
<!-- Form -->
        <div id="contact-form"><form id="contact-form" action="process.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Name: (required)</span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" title="Enter your name" class="required">            
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Email: (required)</span>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" title="Enter your email" class="required">         
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Telephone: (required)</span>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your Telephone" title="Enter your telephone" class="required">         
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Website: (required)</span>
                    <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Your Website" title="Enter your website">            
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Message: (required)</span>
                    <textarea placeholder="Include all the details you can" name="message" type="text" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Send Email</button>
            </div>
        </form></div>
        <!-- /Form -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jss/scripts.js"></script>
```

I want to reset form after 3 seconds and make thank you.... after 3 seconds`

Comment: So you mean the user should enter everything in less than 3seconds? I don't get the sense of this

Comment: It's a reverse captcha check, you have to be a bot to be able to submit this form.

Comment: @RononDex I think OP means to do it after user submits the form.

Comment: ha ha reverse captcha check :P

Comment: Pay attention that you have 2 id's with the same name , this could break functionality .

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Form.reset();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Fform.reset)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
}, 3000);
```

I have prepared a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HDf5B/)

Comment: he has also "contact-form" id of a div this will not work if you don't provide the form id which is uniuqe

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(resetForm, 3000); // Call the reset form function in 3000 ms or 3 sec

function resetForm(){
    $("form#contact-form")[0].reset(); // Use the form.reset function
}
```

If you want to do it on form submit, do it like this:

```
$("form#contact-form").submit(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){this.reset()}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but jQuery object does not have `reset()` It should be `$("form#contact-form")[0].reset();`

Answer (score 0):

try this

first give a unique id to your form

```
<form id="my_contact_form" action="process.php" method="post">
```

now you can use given JAVASCRIPT

```
setInterval(function(){
    var oForm = document.getElementById('my_contact_form');

    var frm_elements = oForm.elements;
   for (i = 0; i < frm_elements.length; i++)
{
    field_type = frm_elements[i].type.toLowerCase();
    switch (field_type)
    {
    case "text":
    case "password":
    case "textarea":
    case "hidden":
        frm_elements[i].value = "";
        break;
    case "radio":
    case "checkbox":
        if (frm_elements[i].checked)
        {
            frm_elements[i].checked = false;
        }
        break;
    case "select-one":
    case "select-multi":
        frm_elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;
        break;


       default:
            break;
        }
    }

},3000);
```

this will clear all fields of your form after 3 seconds

see [**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DUa2N/)